# nth term of a sequence which according to me is not an AP, GP or HP

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The first term of a sequence is 2014 . Each succeeding term is the sum of the cubes of the digits of the previous term. Then the $2014^{\text {th }}$ term of the sequence is

I thought of doing it by writing recurrence relation but unable to do so

Comment: Why not calculate a few terms of the sequence, and see where it goes?

Comment: Thanks, I got it

Comment: @Randomuser if you answer your own question you get a badge, idk if thats something ur interested in.

Comment: you are correct it's not AP, GP, or HP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write few terms and you will notice after some terms, 370 starts repeating as sum of cubes of digits of 370 is equal to 370 itself